# Is there a way to send an automated email from two consecutive identical Google form entries in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-forms

school admin guy here.

We are using Google Forms for our attendance registers at our language academy.

The google form uses a checkbox grid with student names as rows and the following options as columns:

- Present
- Absent
- Late
- Online
- Missing Homework

These responses are sent to Spreadsheets which are manually checked by admin staff.

We currently have a system whereby teachers are supposed to verbally inform admin staff if students are absent for two classes or more consecutively, but many do not work in the centre and maybe forget to update admin.

I have been searching for a script which will trigger an email to a specified email address if a student has an "Absent" entry two times in a row, but also resets when the student re-attends again.

Alternatively the students name (info in Row 1) who is absent 2x consecutively could be added to an alternative spreadsheet for compiling.

Hoping someone can help! Thanks!

[In this example Sofia Vergara (I wish!) was absent three times in a row so an email should be triggered after the second absence. Then reset after she attends the fourth class (E5). Juan Lopez then is absent for two classes in a row and should be added to the absentee list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc8rZ.jpg)

Comment: I think that it is possible using formSubmit trigger for the quickest reaction or any time based trigger if once per day is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Launch once myTriggerSetup

```
const adresseEmail = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'

function myTriggerSetup() {
  if(!isTrigger('onFormSubmit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
     var r=false;
     if(funcName) {
       var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
       var allHandlers=[];
       for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) {
         allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
       }
       if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1) {
         r=true;
       }
     }
     return r;
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = e.values.length + 1;
  for (var i=2;i<=column;i++){
    if (sheet.getRange(row,i).getValue()=='Absent' && sheet.getRange(row-1,i).getValue()=='Absent'){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: adresseEmail,
        subject: 'Consecutive absences ' + sheet.getName(),
        htmlBody: sheet.getRange(1,i).getValue(), 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Awesome thanks!!! I've been fiddling with the code for an hour now, but is there a way to add the name of the sheet to the subject? Eg. "Consecutive absences in "Sheet Name"? This will save our admin staff a lot of time! Once again, Thank you so much Mike!

Comment: Yes, by this mean `subject: 'Consecutive absences ' + sheet.getName(),` I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike!

Comment: Please check the answer so that it is highlighted for other requesters.